# PHP files not downloading - headers not prompting download

Tags: php, download, header, php-ziparchive, response-headers

I am having an issue where I am attempting to prompt the browser to open a save dialog when doing a readfile with a zip file. I have exhausted basically every other resource I can find. I have confirmed that headers were not being sent prematurely (no errors and headers_sent() return false on testing), and I can also see the correct response headers when I inspect the response in Chrome/Firefox. The file essentially gets returned as binary, but does not prompt for download. Using PHP 7.2 and Apache 2.4. Any help would be great, no idea where I am going wrong at this point.

```
    public function downloadFile() {
        $tmpfile = '/path/to/file.zip';
        header('Content-Type: octet-stream');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($tmpfile));
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($tmpfile));
        ob_clean();
        readfile($tmpfile);
        exit();
    }
```

This is being requested via a GET request, and if I use Postman, and the "Send and Download" feature, I can save the file, and it is a valid zip just as expected, but I just can't get the browser to download.

**EDIT:** I want to add that octet-stream is wrong, but after changing it to **application/octet-stream** there was no change. I have also tried **application/zip**.

Here are also the response headers that I get back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 16:13:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) PHP/7.2.18
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.18
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Length: 386
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=97
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

**EDIT #2:**
I have also tried adding the following with no success.

```
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mime-type is missing a portion:
application/octet-stream

Comment: I tried that but I got the same result. I have also tried application/zip.

Answer (score 0):

Try this header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

instead of

```
header('Content-Type: octet-stream');
```

Edit:
This may be valid, too (untested):

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
```

Edit 2:
Add these headers which are mentioned here when use readfile():

```
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#refsect1-function.readfile-examples

Comment: I tried that but I got the same result. I have also tried application/zip.

Comment: I added those headers as well with no change.